# get_user_meta value is stored within strange characters

Tags: user-meta, meta-value

I'm trying to access an ID stored within a user profile using the `add_user_meta` and the `get_user_meta` function to return the ID, but when I print the values out I am given this strange value. I can see that the ID is inside it but don't quite understand how to encode it to just show the value without all the other stuff.  `[school_id] => Array ( [0] => a:1:{i:0;i:88;} )`

***How the data is being added***

````
/*
* Create new custom post type post on new user registration
*/
add_action( 'user_register', 'add_user_to_school_cpt', 10, 1 );
function add_user_to_school_cpt( $user_id )
{
   // Get user info
   $user_info = get_userdata( $user_id );

   // Create a new post
   $school_post = array(
       'post_title'   => get_field('name', 'user_' . $user_id), 
       'post_content' => $user_info->description,
       'post_type'    => 'school',
       'post_status'  => 'publish',
       'post_author'  => $user_id,
   );

   // Insert the post into the database
   $school_id = wp_insert_post( $school_post );

   // Add the school ID as a meta data
   add_user_meta( $user_id, 'school_id', [$school_id] );

   // Add school custom fields
   add_post_meta( $school_id, 'email', $user_info->user_email );
   add_post_meta( $school_id, 'school_telephone', get_field('telephone', 'user_' . $user_id) );
   add_post_meta( $school_id, 'school_city', get_field('city', 'user_' . $user_id) );
   add_post_meta( $school_id, 'school_postcode', get_field('postcode', 'user_' . $user_id) );
   add_post_meta( $school_id, 'school_address', get_field('address', 'user_' . $user_id) );
} ```
````

Comment: It's a [serialized](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) array. The value should be getting unserialized by `get_user_meta()`, so if its not then you've done something wrong when inserting the data. How are you adding this data?

Comment: Ahh I see. I've added the code that is being used to add the data. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is with this line:

```
   // Add the school ID as a meta data
   add_user_meta( $user_id, 'school_id', [$school_id] );
```

No need for the array brackets when you store the user meta, change it to:

```
   // Add the school ID as a meta data
   add_user_meta( $user_id, 'school_id', $school_id );
```

Comment: Turned out to be that I needed to use the maybe_unserialize( string $data ) function :)

Comment: Interesting, thanks for sharing